# How to clean CSV having double quote with-in double quote using R

Tags: r, csv

Below is csv row which i am reading using R. But not getting all value separated in their column as I am having commas and inverted comma in data set.

Data: "18452","xx, yy & zz "Charles W","xxxx"

```
Desire Data Frame : 
        Col A -> 18452
        Col B -> xx, yy & zz "Charles W
        Col C -> "xxxx"

OR
    Col A -> 18452
    Col B -> xx, yy & zz Charles W
    Col C -> "xxxx"

Any one will work.
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you meant `xxxx` and not `"xxxx"` as output for the last column replace each occurrence of `","` (i.e. each occurrence of double quote, comma, double quote) with `|` and remove any double quote at the beginning and end of each line.  Finally, read using `read.table`:

```
read.table(text = gsub('^"|"$', "", gsub('","', '|', Data)), sep = "|", quote = "")
```

giving:

```
     V1                     V2   V3
1 18452 xx, yy & zz "Charles W xxxx
```

A variation of the above is to express it as a magrittr pipeline:

```
library(magrittr)

Data %>% 
     gsub(pattern = '^"|"$', replacement = "") %>%
     gsub(pattern = '","', replacement = '|') %>%
     read.table(text = ., sep = "|", quote = "")
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form is:

```
Data <- '"18452","xx, yy & zz "Charles W","xxxx"'
```

Comment: replacing , with |..will it not create another col while reading as the col b also have commas

Comment: The code does NOT replace commas with pipes.  It replaces a double quote followed by a comma followed by a double quote with a pipe.  A comma in a field will NOT be replaced as can be seen in the example shown in the answer.  V2 has a comma and it was not replaced.